# Trying to add ACF to authors meta and adding a class at the same time

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add a an acf field called "name" while also adding a css-class to it

```
the_field('name')
```

to this code

```
if ($go_magazine_options['post_meta_author'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop()) {    
    echo '<span class="client">' . get_the_field('name') .
   '<span class="entry-meta-author author vcard"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a class="fn" href="' . 
   esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '">' . 
   esc_html(get_the_author()) . '</a></span>' . "\n";
}
```

but something is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little Aprilia learns to code ;-)
was a silly idea to mix two things, justed added the ACF-Field, using its own if-rule

```
if( get_field('apri') ): ?>
<span class= "promo"><?php the_field('apri'); ?></span>
<?php endif;
```